# Django migration error when changing manytomany field to Foreign key

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Initially my models.py looked liked this

```
class P (models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=100);

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

class T (models.Model):
    p_id=models.ManyToManyField(P)
```

Everything was working great. then i changed class T as below:

```
class T (models.Model):
        p_id=models.ForeignKey(P,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None,null=True)
#I have added default values coz django asks me to during migrations
```

I get following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "p_id_id" does not exist
```

Previously when such error happened I used to delete all tables from Postgresql DB, then comment out entire models.py in my app, run a fake migration, then uncomment models.py and run migrations again and it would work. But this destroys all data in DB. Is there a way to make it work without deleting any data?

Comment: What if you write it with two migrations? First remove the m2m, then make a migration, and then add the `ForeignKey` and again make a migration? Furthermore it is logical that it destroys the data: an m2m is fundamentally different from a foreign key.

Comment: Since an m2m model means one can have zero, one, or multiple `P`s for a `T`, it would be weird to resolve that. What would you do in case there are multiple `P`s?

Comment: I tried commenting out m2m and made migration, but got error--
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "p_id_id" of relation "appname_t" does not exist. 
I checked in my current DB, every T has a unique P. 1 T can only have 1 P. but 1P can have multiple T's.

Comment: That is because the migration you did, actually was resolved *partially* (yes I know, this is really one of the problematic parts of Django, that if a migration goes wrong, it stays that way as a "partially resolved", and thus when you migrate again, you can no longer do the changes, since some changes are already done).

Comment: You shouldn't comment out fields. But you should write several migrations: first, add the FK field; then, copy the values from the M2M, and finally, remove the M2M.

Comment: Django won’t let me add a FK field from P class when there already is a m2m field from P class. How can I convert a m2m to a FK without destroying the data.

Answer (score 0):

The error I talk about in my question is perhaps coz i ran fake migration with p_id as as FK in models.py which told Django that p_id_id already exists in DB , just create a migration file. When i retried everything from scratch without fake migration the error disappeared.

Django wont change m2m to FK (one to many) automatically, and that makes sense. If i run migrations after changing m2m to FK , the mapping table appname_t_p gets deleted and data is lost forever. I did following and it worked:

Manually backed up mapping table created during m2m 'appname_t_p'.

```
create table atp as select * from appname_t_p;
```

change m2m to FK in models.py ( as shown in the question) . then ran migrations (not fake migration). This created a new all nulls column p_id_id in T table.

Then manually wrote sql update statement to add values from above backed-up table atp into p_id_id (all NULLS) column in table appname_t.

```
UPDATE appname_t t1
SET    p_id_id = t2.p_id
FROM   atp t2
WHERE  t2.t_id = t1.id;
```

Then verified values and it was right.